# Calculating day difference between two dates

Tags: date, stata, days

My variable `DateBecame` looks like this:

```
19550101
```

It is of `long` type and the format is `%10.0g`. So `YMD` format.

I also have another variable `DateLeft`:

```
19961001
```

This is also of `long` type and format `%10.0g`.

How can I calculate the duration between the two dates?

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me:

```
clear

input long(date1 date2)
19550101 19961001
end 

generate diff = daily(string(date1, "%10.0g"), "YMD") - ///
                daily(string(date2, "%10.0g"), "YMD")

list

     +---------------------------------+
     |    date1      date2        diff |
     |---------------------------------|
  1. | 19550101   19961001      -15249 |
     +---------------------------------+
```

Note that variables of `long` type are generally not ideal for this kind of calculations.

Type `help datetime` from Stata's command prompt for more information on working with dates.